# Android Studio - Adding library/code search paths to Gradle?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I am still new to Android Studio after the switch since I never needed more than getting my old Eclipse code to compile which never used anything but included libraries, popular .jar files and single source-code-files I could simply add to my project.

But now I need to use a charting library
https://code.google.com/p/android-charts/

So I downloaded it as placed it here: D:\AndroidStudioLibs\AndroidCharts\

There are no .jar files.

I can not find any relevant options in any of the "File" settings related menus.

After searching Google, I found some people manually edit the *build.gradle* file and add search paths at top:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'file:/D:/AndroidStudioLibs' }
        maven { url 'file:/D:/AndroidStudioLibs/AndroidCharts/bin/classes/cn/limc/androidcharts' }
    }
}
```

I also added this

```
dependencies {
    compile 'cn.limc:androidcharts:1.0.0'
}
```

However, I am not able to get it to compile, and I feel I may also be running up the wrong tree here.

Following @Kishan suggestion I got a new error:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY902.png

My project structure dialog
[image]

Comment: That library's installation instructions are rather bizarre. That being said, did you follow those [Gradle build instructions](https://github.com/limccn/Android-Charts#gradle-build)? I think that they imply that you have `mavenLocal()` in your `repositories` closure in your app's project, which they fail to mention. Also, those "search paths" would go in a `repositories` closure that is a peer of `dependencies`, not the one in `buildscript`.

Comment: I will try investigate and learn more about Gradles and mavens and try what you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android studio , import your chart library as module an then add this module dependency in your project.

@Tom

In *AndroidCharts*'s **build.gradle** file, you'll see a statement like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

which tells Gradle to build it as an application, generating an **APK**. If you change it to this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

it will build as a library, generating an **AAR**, and it should work.

Comment: I tried to do as you suggested and while I may have gotten further - I still get an error. I have (or will very soon) uploaded a screenshot

Comment: I got it to compile now. (Thanks! Major step forward) But does it still need assets, res, AndroidManifest.xml etc. file? I tried to remove these files, but it appers Android Studio believes the library needs to have its own AndroidManifest file? Also, no matter what I do, Android Studio now appears to think my entire project is called AndroidCharts and I am not allowed to switch back to my primary project. (I would have though I could "switch" between them in the same structure view)

Comment: If I leave the AndroidManifest.xml file in the AndroidCharts project - I get collisions if I right-click on my "app"  and click "Make module app". However, commenting out large sections in that file solves that problem. Still, it appears somewhat messy and still cant actually build app to mobile since I can not select my original "app" project - it tries to build "AndroidCharts".

Comment: Nevermind - seems I successfully confused myself. I got the app compiling to my mobile phone now. Still a bit puzzled about the other things, but I got it working now. I will create a new SO if I have problems using the library. Thanks again everyone!

Comment: Create new project and then add your library as module